# check whether an element exists using jQuery

Tags: jquery, conditional-operator

I want to make the jquery working only when the particular #id or .class is available. i want to know which one is correct ??? please help... Thanks

```
if($().flexslider) {
//do something
}

or

if ( $( '#flexslider' ).length && jQuery().flexslider ) {
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You `safely` use length to determine if the DOM element `exists`.

```
if ( $('#flexslider').length) //For item with id flexslider
```

or

```
if ( $('.classname').length) //For item with class classname
```

To check if function exists

```
if ($.isFunction(window.yourFunName))        //with jQuery

if(typeof(callback) == "function")           //with javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the element exists, and the flexslider plugin is loaded, do the latter:

```
if ( $( '#flexslider' ).length && jQuery().flexslider ) {
    //do something
}
```

If you only want to check if the element exists, do this:

```
if($('#flexslider').length) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct is in the eye of the beholder most of the time. There's often multiple ways to solve an issue. If you want to check for the presence of a bound function and the existence of a DOM Node, then you'll need to capture both after the `ready` function and compare the `typeof` variable to function to see if it's true.

```
$(function(){
    if($('#flexslider').length && typeof flexslider == 'function'){

    }
});
```